# HTML5 Video iOS11 issue

Tags: html, email, html5-video, html-email, ios11

I've used the code from EmailOnAcid for implementing HTML5 video into e-mails, and it works in all clients,except for the standard mail client in iOS11.
https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a_how_to_guide_to_embedding_html5_video_in_email
The thumbnail of the video is shown, but it just keeps buffering, and never plays. The only way to get iOS11 to play the video, is by closing the e-mail app, and reopening it. Then it can play the video.

Is there a solution for this, or at least some CSS to target iOS11 to make a fallback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to target iOS 11. Below is the code to target different versions.

Here's a media query that will target iOS 10:

```
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch) and (color:#ffff) {
/* Insert CSS here */
}
```

If you’d like to specifically target iOS Mail in the most recent version of Apple’s operating system—that’s iOS 11.0, 11.1, or 11.2—@support declarations combined with padding properties will do the trick:

*Target iOS 11.0 & 11.1*

```
@supports (padding-left:constant(safe-area-inset-left)) {
/* Insert CSS here */
}
```

*Target iOS 11.2*

```
@supports (padding-left:env(safe-area-inset-left)) {
/* Insert CSS here */
}
```

[Source](https://litmus.com/blog/what-email-marketers-need-to-know-about-ios-11-and-the-new-iphones)

Hope this helps. 
Also videos are good to engage customers on their device and using plain text with link to videos is old school and just sending people away from your emails. You want them engaged in your emails and complete the journey they started.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't find it anywhere I looked!
Works like a charm and now I can at least show a fallback solution to iOS11 users, and hope HTML5 video in e-mail is fixed in later versions of iOS.

Comment: I think only iOS 11 and 8 have the issues (check it), the rest of the iOS support videos. Glad i could help out. Also keep the source blog handy, it is good.

Answer (score 0):

its wrong to send html emails with embedded multimedia,  you should send plain text with url link to media

Comment: Plain text is old school. If you are thinking about ascii art in emails then wait till you see the fonts people use on their emails :-)